# Mpandroid chart line graph show line behind background color

Tags: java, android, charts

Hello i am using below code in my application but mpandroidchart line graph shows behind the background this is my code

```
float rangeLow = 66f;
float rangeHigh = 120f;

    YAxis fillAxis = lineChart.getAxisLeft();

    float increment = (rangeHigh - rangeLow) / 20;
    float metricLine = rangeLow;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        LimitLine llRange = new LimitLine(metricLine, "");
        llRange.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#f2befb"));
        llRange.setLineWidth(100f);
        fillAxis.addLimitLine(llRange);
        metricLine = metricLine + increment;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
 llRange.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#f2befb"));
```

Use this:

```
 llRange.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#80f2befb"));
```

I added 80 in start of your color which makes it 50% transparent. For transperancy you can add number before your color hex code as follows:

```
0% = #00
10% = #16
20% = #32
30% = #48
40% = #64
50% = #80
60% = #96
70% = #112
80% = #128
90% = #144
```

Comment: If it works then dont forget to mark this post as an answer :)

Comment: I updated answer buddy this will work and please dont forget to mark this post as answer. Thank you :)